# VBA positioning an excel graph

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro whilst creating this graph, generating:

```
Sub Macro13()

    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet!$A$1:$B$100)
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Title"
    'ActiveChart.Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4)     Doesnt work??
End Sub
```

and I'd like to position the graph at particular cells. However, the Left() method wouldn't work on ActiveChart and all the solutions I found were hacky along the lines of:

```
ActiveSheet.Graphs(0).Left() =
```

which I hate because I don't want to guess how many charts are on the sheet.

Is there a way to position the chart using a local variable from when I created the chart above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will move your chart object so the top left corner is in range B2:

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Left = Range("B2").Left
ActiveChart.Parent.Top = Range("B2").Top
```

ActiveChart is the chart - the parent is the chartobject (container for the chart).

Answer (score 0):

This in answer to your last question:

> Is there a way to position the chart using a local variable from when I created the chart above?

This incorporates [Darren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40745808/3866299) while helping you to position new charts based on other charts on the sheet.

```
  Sub newChart()

  Dim newChartPositionLeft As Integer
  Dim newChartPositionTop As Integer
  Dim lastChartAdded As ChartObject
  Dim firstChart As Boolean

  'Turn on error handling. If trying to access a previous chart fails, you know this is the first chart to be added
  On Error Resume Next
    Set lastChartAdded = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      firstChart = True
    Else
      firstChart = False
      newChartPositionTop = lastChartAdded.Top + lastChartAdded.Height + 5 'Increase this number to add padding between charts
      newChartPositionLeft = lastChartAdded.Left 'Aligning the new chart with the previous one
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0

   'Your original code
   Columns("A:B").Select
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet!$A$1:$B$100")
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
   ActiveChart.Legend.Select
   Selection.Delete

   'Positioning the new chart
   If firstChart Then
     ActiveChart.Parent.Left = Range("B2").Left
     ActiveChart.Parent.Top = Range("B2").Top
   Else
     ActiveChart.Parent.Left = newChartPositionLeft
     ActiveChart.Parent.Top = newChartPositionTop
   End If


End Sub
```